# NCache Serializes object and then throws OutOfMemoryException after only 67MB

Tags: .net, ncache

The object should ultimately serialize to about 350MB which is well under the limit for 32 bit apps.

I am setting up my own Compact Serializer so I can control serialization and I am finding that the MemoryStream consumption is reaching a Capacity of 67,108,864 bytes and the position is 59,913,379 and it throws an OutOfMemoryException.
Is there any workaround for this? 
My object is recursive and the serialize method is called recursively is there any problem with allocation that comes from this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

```
    [Serializable]
    public class TestObject : ICompactSerializable
    {
        public int[] testArray = new int[]{};
        public List<TestObject> testOfSelf = new List<TestObject>();
        public TestObject()
        {

        }
        public TestObject(TestObject insert)
        {
            testOfSelf.Add(insert);
        }


        public void Deserialize(Alachisoft.NCache.Runtime.Serialization.IO.CompactReader reader)
        {
            this.testArray = reader.ReadObjectAs<int[]>();
            this.testOfSelf = reader.ReadObjectAs<List<TestObject>>();
        }

        public void Serialize(Alachisoft.NCache.Runtime.Serialization.IO.CompactWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteObject(this.testArray);
            writer.WriteObject(this.testOfSelf);
        }
    }
```

```
        TestObject rootNode = new TestObject();
        int maxArray = 1000;
        int factor = 110058451;
        int ratchetBackDivisor = 5;
        var intArray = from o in new int[maxArray] select rand.Next(0, 10000);
        var sixty_seven_million_lessKilloByte = factor / maxArray;
        int recursionDepth = 20;
        int flatLevel = 5;
            Action<int,TestObject> recursion = null;
            recursion = (i,recurse) =>
                {
                    var newT = new TestObject();
                    newT.testArray = (from o in new int[maxArray] select rand.Next(0, 10000)).ToArray();

                    if (i != 0)
                    {
                        recursion(--i, newT);
                    }
                    recurse.testOfSelf.Add(newT);
                };
            for (int i = 0; i < ((sixty_seven_million_lessKilloByte / recursionDepth) / ratchetBackDivisor); i++)
            {
                //for (int j = 0; j < flatLevel; i++)
                {
                    var to = new TestObject();
                    recursion(recursionDepth, to);
                    rootNode.testOfSelf.Add(to);
                }                
            }
            long length = 0;
            using (Stream S = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BinaryFormatter bw = new BinaryFormatter();
                bw.Serialize(S, rootNode);
                length = S.Length;
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format(@"Total size of object is {0}", S.Length.ToString("#,##0")));
            }
```

Using this I get an System.OutOfMemoryException when the length is 94610430

Comment: Should not happen. Can you please share some of your code ? The error might be in your serialization method.

Comment: Given an object like the following

Comment: Tried it. Works fine for me. It prints for me `Total size of object is 94,749,084`

Comment: And when you're using BinaryFormatter you are not using `Alachisoft.NCache.Runtime.Serialization.ICompactSerializable`

Comment: Adds in a local cache as well

Comment: Basit Can you try to see where the breaking point is? There are some notes that say to keep the NCache Max cache size below 1600 to prevent those problems. But I still see exception occur intermittently. As far as the serialization with Binary Formatter I am only doing this so I can determine the size.

Comment: There is no limit to the cache size. I'll take a look at your code closely and let you know

Comment: What could possibly be different on my setup that is causing this? Are you running 32bit or 64bit? Is there some version or parameter of NCache that is different between us?

Comment: Wait you're running Windows x32?

Comment: yes I am running 32 bit

Comment: Works fine for me. Keeping the Test Object same here is the code that i tested on a 32 bit machine (Windows x86) - 

http://collabedit.com/e6dvc

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114020/ncache-serialize

Comment: Can you paste the whole exception ?